# Why does my mysql query for getting "most" data just run forever?

Tags: mysql

I have a user table ldap_karen that has all employee data including sup_id (supervisor id) and the employee's job role.

I also I have a supervisor table that has all the unique sup_ids.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT
ldap_sups.sup_id,
COUNT(ldap_karen.uid) as team_nums,
COUNT(sa_title) as title_nums,
(SELECT sa_title
FROM ldap_karen
WHERE ldap_sups.sup_id=ldap_karen.sup_id
group by sa_title
order by count(ldap_karen.sa_title) desc
limit 1) as sup_role,
ldap_karen.sa_title,
ldap_karen.regionname
FROM
ldap_sups
JOIN ldap_karen ON ldap_sups.sup_id = ldap_karen.sup_id
GROUP BY sup_id
```

So this gives me the supervisor ID, then number of team members, number of job titles (not all employees have job titles), sup_role - this is what is not working, sa_title (which just lists the job title of the last person in the list), and region.

I would like sup_role to display the "most" job title.  So whatever job titles comes up the most for the employee under the supervisor is the sup_role.

**Note:**  Right now my query just runs - due to an issue with the "sup_role" query.  Nothing outputs.

Comment: This seems like it should work. Could you explain what is going wrong? Do you get an error message?
Also, could it be that `WHERE ldap_sups.sup_id=ldap_karen.thomssupervisorid` should be `WHERE ldap_sups.sup_id=ldap_karen.sup_id` ?

Comment: @TeddyOrt - this just runs... never outputs anything.  And yes that was an edit mistake on my question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but its not the best way:

```
SELECT
  ldap_sups.sup_id,
  COUNT(ldap_karen.uid) as team_nums,
  COUNT(ldap_karen.sa_title) as title_nums,
  sums_title.sa_title as sup_role,
  ldap_karen.sa_title,
  ldap_karen.regionname
FROM
  ldap_sups
  JOIN ldap_karen ON ldap_sups.sup_id = ldap_karen.sup_id
  LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT sup_id, max(sum), sa_title from  
                (SELECT sup_id, count(sa_title) as sum, sa_title
                FROM ldap_karen
                group by  sa_title,sup_id) supsup
            group by sup_id
          ) as sums_title on sums_title.sup_id = ldap_sups.sup_id
GROUP BY sup_id
```

Comment: Did you got output? I proved this and it was fine.

Comment: It never outputs.  I have 80K employees so wondering if the it is the file size or something.

Comment: It should work, try a new "test"-table with less data.

Comment: But I need it to work for 80k employees.  The whole point of the question.